# What is the effect of number of hidden layers on local optimas in neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

How does the number of hidden layers, affect local minimas?
is it because of only the number of parameters or the depth of the network?
for example a network of 5 hidden layer with each having 500 neurons is more prune to local minimas or a network of 2 hidden layes with 1250 neurons each?

Comment: Thanks, Just flagged it so it can be moved there if possible.

Comment: A.I. proposal is going private beta in few days, so unfortunately migration won't be possible.